# How to get to resource 'R.raw.img' + r in java?

Tags: java, android, resources

I have image resources `img1,img2,...img10`,how to reference them dynamically in the code below?

```
    for (int r=1; r<=10; r++){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        ImageView im = new ImageView (this);
        im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.raw.img1));
     ...
```

What I want to do is to get reference to `'R.raw.img' + r`...

Comment: Your title is incomprehensibly generic.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: If you could post the relevant section of your xml file that might help.

Comment: @SapphireSun: How is Java not a relevant tag?

Comment: @John: I felt it was too generic. It wasn't a question about the language, just about Android (which is understood to only run on Java). It could reasonably go either way though I felt.

Answer (score 3):

This is not merely possible in the way you said.
Here is a solution:
You need a typed array in the resources and use it like described on [this site from Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray).
In short, create your resource file like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="pictures">
        <item>@drawable/img1</item>
        <item>@drawable/img2</item>
        <item>@drawable/img3</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Code this way,

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray pics = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.pictures);
```

You can then iterate through the array like this,

```
for (i.....)
    Drawable drawable = pics.getDrawable(i);
```

Comment: It is appreciated if you explain it anyway as link rot is a problem.  We don't want this answer to become useless for the next person.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed it as you've suggested. However, I do suspect if this link could possibly rot.

Comment: Yes, it's rumored even Google can rot. ;)  Next time you respond to someone, I recommend adding @[NAME] to the beginning, where [NAME] is the persons name(obviously).  That way, the system will notify them of your response.  You are being notified of this response without me having to add "@Gene" because you own the answer I am commenting on.

Comment: @John You are very helpful and thank you for helping such a lot. Hope I did it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest is to do:

```
int[] images = new int[]{
    R.raw.img1, R.raw.img2 .... 
};
for (int r=1; r<=10; r++){
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    ImageView im = new ImageView (this);
    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(images[i]));
 ...
```

If you wanna get rid of the array, you need reflection

Comment: How does this give him references/handles to the resources?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Bitmap _scratch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1);
```

You will need to import Bitmap and BitmapFactory.  `_scratch` is a working handle to the resource `R.drawable.img1`

Comment: @java: Then how *do* you want to use it?  If for drawing to the screen, `_scratch` is my example is a working handle.

Comment: @java: Whatever you are using it for, at least try it and see if it works.